# regex: specify that group should NOT be a certain word

Tags: php, regex

`/^(.+?) (is|was) an? (.+?)$/` is my current regular expression for PHP's `preg_match` function.

But I don't want it to match the sentence: `"what is a dog"` or `"who is a dog"`. So I have to somehow specify that the words 'what' and 'who' should not be matched for the first group.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Edit: Just to clarify, I want it to match sentences like `"Buddy is an animal"` and `"jsbvsjvdhbjsbjhv is a dog"`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a negative lookbehind, right before the `(is|was)` group:

```
/^(.+?)(?<!what|who) (is|was) an? (.+)$/
```

Note that I removed the ungreedy quantifier from the last subpattern - since you want to match as much as possible to get to the end of the string, it's inefficient to tell it to match as little as possible.

Comment: I was aware of "negative lookbehind", but an illustrative example is always welcome! TY

Answer (score -1):

```
/^((([^w]|w[^h]|wh[^ao]|wha[^t]|what.|who.).* is)|(.+?) was) an? (.+?)$/
```

:)

Correction, misunderstood the question: (`what was a.*` and `who was a.*` should also be excluded). So even simpler:

```
/^([^w]|w[^h]|wh[^ao]|wha[^t]|what.|who.).* (is|was) an? (.+?)$/
```